# GPX File - Adding a Global Attribute That Applies to All Track Points

Tags: gps, gpx

I am running a process where I am creating a GPX file from a GPS enabled video.  What I want to do is embed the video file name into a GPX file attribute so that when I “click on” a GPX point, I get the file name as an attribute.

I could use the NAME attribute/tag and apply that to every track point, thousands of them, but I would like to see if I could add something to the header that would apply the file name to all track points as an attribute. Sort of like the TRKPT tag.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the GPX schema (http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd) it looks like you should use the metadata link element to give a link to a video that applies to all points.

[image: GPX schema]